# MySQL prepared statement is slower than the hard coded query, unless I turn PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES off

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My query is:

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("  SELECT    balance, currency
                         FROM      balances
                         WHERE     user_id = ?
                         ORDER BY  date_utc DESC 
                                   LIMIT 1");
    try {
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        echo 'Executed in: ' . number_format((microtime(true) - $microtime),4).' sec';
```

My table is:

```
id          bigint          pkey      
user_id     bigint          fkey     index
balance     decimal(19,4)
date_utc    date                     index
```

My index is:

```
ALTER TABLE balances ADD INDEX user_id_date_utc (user_id, date_utc)
```

If I execute the above code, the runtime is **`Executed in: 0.0098 sec`**

But if I change the code to hardcode user_id like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("  SELECT    balance, currency
                     FROM      balances
                     WHERE     user_id = 2
                     ORDER BY  date_utc DESC 
                               LIMIT 1");
```

My performance skyrockets to: **`Executed in: 0.0005 sec`**

This is with `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false`, but if I toggle this to `true`, then I get the improved performance!

But I'm concerned that this 20x performance increase, must be coming at some hidden cost?

On the other hand, isn't the query I'm executing is simple enough, that surely it must be possible to execute safely, with quick performance?

My question: does `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true` still offer the protection I expect from using prepared statements?

Comment: `EMULATE_PREPARES` isn't _strictly_ prepared statements, it emulates them in PHP and then sends the query to MySQL. Turning that off just makes the driver actually use MySQL's prepared statements. This functionality mainly exists to accommodate DB backends that _don't_ natively support prepared statements. The only difference that I can think of is that sometimes PHP's prepares allow you to bind variables in places that MySQL does not, which are places you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: TL;DR: _Both_ have the benefits of prepared statements, pick the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: @Sammitch Why "shouldn't" you use parameters in LIMIT? That seems like an arbitrary MySQL restriction, and `EMULATES_PREPARES` works around it.

Comment: When you hard-code the ID value into the SQL, the index lookup is done by the query planner, rather than doing it dynamically when the statement is executed. This makes the execution faster.

Comment: 1. How far is your mysql server from PHP? Should explain only 2x increase, not 20 though. What if   `$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->execute();` instead of `$stmt->execute(array($id));`?

Comment: Run each query twice.  The 10ms difference could be "startup overhead.".

Comment: I'll have to double check @RickJames to make sure it's not startup overhead.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What do you mean "how far"? Physical server location should be constant in both cases? It's a separate cloud DB though, so not on the same Compute VM.

Comment: The same city (for client and server) is close enough not to matter.  Separate continents is a big deal.